# azure billing api runs Ok but returns nothing to view?

Tags: .net, api, azure, billing

I'm using the [`billing-dotnet-usage-api`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-usage-api).
I have configured it correctly and it connects to azure, no errors.
I get a black cmd window which says:

> Calling Usage service...
>   Usage service response status: OK
>   Usage stream received.  Press ENTER to continue with raw output.
>
> {"value":[]}
>   Raw output complete.  Press ENTER to continue with JSON output.
>
> {"value":[]}
>   JSON output complete.  Press ENTER to close.

When I press enter it closes and goes back to visual studio but I get no data or anything relating to costs/billing/breakdowns.. Nothing?!

Have I missed something..?
Thanks

Comment: Please check the input parameters you're passing.

Comment: Yes I needed to change the date range! I missed it ;). But now I am getting all the raw data and have worked how to save it as a txt file. But I don't know how to use this data?? It's useless..  I thought this API would provide me with an interface that I could use to view the data in a meaningful way...?

Answer (score 1):

The API provides your usage data separate from the rates charged, you have to do the work to calculate the charges yourself. Basically you have to retrieve your usage using the [Usage API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219001) and then the rates for your subscription using the [Rates API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004). Then you have to calculate the charges by joining the usage to the rates on the Meterid GUID.

The example app from the team hosted [here](https://github.com/Azure/BillingCodeSamples) contains the code to convert the JSON data to C# objects.

I have a post [here](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2016/02/using-azure-billing-api/) that explains how to do the calculations in more detail.